# Setting up ssh tunnel through multiple hosts and with different users

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have the following ssh connections:

```
    user1@local --> root@machine1 --> root@machine2 --> abc@machine3
```

I need to be able to connect from local directly to machine3:

```
    [user1@local]$ ssh abc@machine3
```

At this point I'm fine if I need to enter passwords, though ideally I would like to use ssh keys and no password connections.

I'm able to connect to machine1 and machine2 with sudo, but connecting to machine3 fails:

```
[user1@local]$ sudo ssh abc@machine3
root@machine1.com's password:
root@machine2.com's password:
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

My /root/.ssh/config file contains the following:

```
    Host machine1
        HostName machine1.com
        User root
        IdentitiesOnly yes

    Host machine2
        HostName machine2.com
        User root
        ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p machine1
        IdentitiesOnly yes

    Host machine3
        HostName machine3.com
        User abc
        ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p machine2
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I'm on OpenSSH_5.3p1 on local machine, hence cannot use ProxyJump.  Also there is no netcat support on machines 1,2 and 3.

When I ssh manually, I can only ssh to machine3 from machine2 as abc user and then there is no password required (authorized_keys on machine3 contains public key from machine2).  Connecting manually as any other user to machine3 from machine2 results in the same Permission denied error as above.

Any idea how to achieve the desired ssh connection from local machine?  Is this doable?  Once the tunnel is set I'll need to create some files on machine3 and restart services there - all from script.

**EDIT**

I tried ssh with verbose and got this:

```
    [user1@local]$ sudo ssh -v abc@machine3
    OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
    debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
    debug1: Applying options for machine3
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Applying options for *
    debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W machine3.com:22 machine2
    debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 0
    debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    root@machine1.com's password:
    root@machine2.com's password:
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
    debug1: Host 'machine3.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4
    debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
    debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

The only file that exists in .ssh directory on machine3 is authorized_keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying an existing answer in [another, related question](https://superuser.com/questions/523393/setting-up-ssh-config-file-with-id-rsa-through-tunnel) I did the following and some/all of it resolved my issue:

1. Copied private and public keys from machine1 and machine2 to local, with different names: /root/.ssh/id_rsa_machine1, /root/.ssh/id_rsa_machine1.pub and /root/.ssh/id_rsa_machine2, /root/.ssh/id_rsa_machine2.pub.
2. Generated ssh keys on local system.
3. Added public key from local system to authorized_keys on machine3.
4. Added public key from local to machine1.
5. Added public key from machine1 to machine2 (machine3 already had public key from machine2 in authorized_keys).
6. Modified /root/.ssh/config file on local so it looks as follows:

   ```
   Host machine1
       HostName machine1.com
       User root
       IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa_machine1
       Port 22
       IdentitiesOnly yes

   Host machine2
       HostName machine2.com
       User root
       IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa_machine2
       Port 22
       ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p machine1
       IdentitiesOnly yes
       ForwardAgent yes


   Host machine3
       HostName machine3.com
       User abc
       ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p machine2
       IdentitiesOnly yes
       ForwardAgent yes
   ```

The identity files referenced need to exist on local machine.  I can now ssh directly with sudo from local to machine3 with no password prompts!  :-)

Made additional changes for user1 on local to ssh as user1 to machine3 directly without password prompts:

1. Copied private and public keys from machine1 and machine2 to user1 .ssh directory on local machine, with the following names: ~/.ssh/id_rsa_machine1, ~/.ssh/id_rsa_machine1.pub and ~/.ssh/id_rsa_machine2, ~/.ssh/id_rsa_machine2.pub.
2. Added public key for user1 on local system to authorized_keys on machine3.

Added the following to user1 ~/.ssh/config file:

```
    Host machine1
        HostName machine1.com
        User root
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_machine1
        Port 22
        IdentitiesOnly yes

    Host machine2
        HostName machine2.com
        User root
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_machine2
        Port 22
        ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p machine1
        IdentitiesOnly yes
        ForwardAgent yes


    Host machine3
        HostName machine3.com
        User abc
        ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p machine2
        IdentitiesOnly yes
        ForwardAgent yes
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you can ssh from machine2 to machine3 means there's a private key on machine2 that can authenticate you against machine3.

You can copy this private key onto local machine and specify its path in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host machine3  
  IdentityFile /path/to/the/key
```